# How to make jar file from javaFX project

Tags: javafx-2

I have javaFX project, with which i'm working on Eclipse IDE. This is Maven project with using of Spring.
My goal is to make runable jar file (dekstop application) from this project.

If i export my application to jar file like any other java project, then i recieve this on error:

```
C:\eclipse\projjars>java -jar EqMan.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\eclipse\bin\glass.dll
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:276)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:122)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:163)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\eclipse\bin\glass.dll
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:143)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:56)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:31)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application$1.run(Application.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:73)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:85)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.<clinit>(WinApplication.java:33)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory.createApplication(WinPlatformFactory.java:20)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory.createApplication(WinPlatformFactory.java:17)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.Run(Application.java:108)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:266)
        ... 5 more
```

If i'm trying to make jar file with javafxpackager, i recieve this one error:

```
C:\eclipse\workspace\equification>javafxpackager -makeall -appclass ru.igs.ava.equification.EquificationFX -name "Equification" -width 800 -height 600
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
C:\eclipse\workspace\equification\src\main\java\ru\igs\ava\equification\EqConfigureRole.java:5: error: package org.springframework.context does not exist
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
C:\eclipse\workspace\equification\src\test\java\ru\igs\ava\equification\AppTest.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    extends TestCase
            ^
//and the same error for every class, which is added to my project as maven dependency.
```

So, how can i make runable jar file without converting my project to NetBeans project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing as you are using Maven for your builds, you can also use Maven to initiate the JavaFX packaging.  To do this use the Maven [antrun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin to invoke the [JavaFX ant tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm) to generate a jar for your application with an embedded JavaFX launcher.  Here is a [sample maven pom](http://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/source/browse/pom.xml) to do this.

---

Your errors in running the javafx packager are due to not appropriately setting the classpath for the packager.  An example of how to set the classpath for the javafx packager to package an application which relies on dependent lib jars is in this [build script](http://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/source/browse/package.bat).

---

The unsatisfied link errors are because you are not including the required lib dll's in a ../bin directory relative to the runtime location of jfxrt.jar when you run your app.  You also might not be correctly packaging your application with a JavaFX launcher (via executing the recommended javafx ant tasks or javafxpackager commands to generate your JavaFX application jar).

**Update**

For Maven based builds of JavaFX applications, you can now use a [Maven JavaFX plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

Going from the suspicion that the underlying problem is due to an incompatibility between jfxrt.jar and the version of Java installed worked for me. The jfxrt.jar the application was using was compatible with jdk-7u71, yet the application was on a machine where JAVA_HOME was set to 7.0.05. So I installed jdk-7u71 on the problem machine and updated JAVA_HOME.