# java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror: com.sun.glass.ui.win.Winapplication._invokelater

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I am tring to run my jar file using java -jar jarfilr.jar command. It is working fine in my system, but when I try to run in other system. I am getting the following error:

Exception in thread main:java.lang.runtimeexception: Application launch error.
Caused by: java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror: com.sun.glass.ui.win.Winapplication._invokelater

Please help me with a solution:

Thanks

Comment: Similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349303/how-to-make-jar-file-from-javafx-project