# UnsatisfiedLinkError on a JavaFX native

Tags: java, jar, javafx, native, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've made a Swing application with some JavaFX content integrated in it. To make it, I used Eclipse and added the JavaFX SDK into the Java Build Path.

When I export the application as a Runnable JAR (*without* using Maven), it works on most of the computers but in some I have an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` on `glass.dll` (or `libglass.so`).

It seems that Java is looking for the native library in the wrong folder, because it says it can't find the library at the working directory of the application (for instance, if I launch the JAR from the Desktop, it says it can't find `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\lib\glass.dll`).

Do you know what is causing this ? Could you help me ? I confirm that the Java version is the latest one on all the computers I've tested.

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make jar file from javaFX project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349303/how-to-make-jar-file-from-javafx-project)

Comment: I have forgotten to tell that I don't use Maven, so I don't know if it's really a duplicate or not.

Comment: Even if you dont use Maven, you can still find the similarity and fix your code !

Comment: Okay, where can I find all the natives used by JavaFX to include them in the /bin directory ?