# jar not launching - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, jar

I have exported my java project into a jar in my desktop (chose the option that creates a project.jar and a project_lib).

When I run `java -jar project.jar` on cmd, I get this exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Application launch error
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:122)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._invokeLater(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._invokeLater(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.invokeLater(Application.java:338)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.defer(QuantumToolkit.java:620)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:173)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runAndWait(PlatformImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.tkExit(PlatformImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:421)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    ... 1 more
```

I guess it is probably caused by my project's paths but I don't know how to fix this.

EDIT: It works fine in eclipse and in my /Desktop directory. Everywhere else, this exception is thrown.

EDIT2: This is the MANIFEST.MF file built:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: . wfmgr_lib/jfxrt.jar wfmgr_lib/junit.jar wfmgr_lib/org.ha
 mcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar wfmgr_lib/gson-2.3.1.jar
Main-Class: main.screens.ScreenFramework
```

EDIT3: I have both jdk 7 and 8 installed. I set up my eclipse project so its compliance level is java-7, building compatible code for the latter.

I also tried using launcher4J and it only worked (in any directory) with the following configurations:

*launch4J.log*:

```
    Version:    3.8
    CmdLine:    C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr_final\wfmgrexe.exe --l4j-debug
    WOW64:      yes
    Working dir:    C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr_final\.
    Bundled JRE:    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
    Check launcher: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (OK)
    Substitute: PATH = C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Check Point\UIFramework 3.0\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\mysql-5.6.25-winx64\mysql-5.6.25-winx64/bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
    Substitute: JAVA_HOME = C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51
    Substitute: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar = 
    Add classpath:  .
    Add classpath:  wfmgr_lib\jfxrt.jar
    Add classpath:  wfmgr_lib\junit.jar
    Add classpath:  wfmgr_lib\org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar
    Add classpath:  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
    Add classpath:  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
    Launcher:   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    Launcher args:  -Denv.path="C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Check Point\UIFramework 3.0\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\mysql-5.6.25-winx64\mysql-5.6.25-winx64/bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" -Denv.java.home="C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51" -Denv.c:\program.files\java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar="" -classpath "C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr_final\wfmgrexe.exe;.;wfmgr_lib\jfxrt.jar;wfmgr_lib\junit.jar;wfmgr_lib\org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" main.screens.ScreenFramework
    Args length:    1008/32768 chars
    Exit code:  0


    Version:    3.8
    CmdLine:    C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr_final\wfmgrexe.exe --l4j-debug
    WOW64:      yes
    Working dir:    C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr_final\.
    Bundled JRE:    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
    Check launcher: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (OK)
    Substitute: PATH = C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Check Point\UIFramework 3.0\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\mysql-5.6.25-winx64\mysql-5.6.25-winx64/bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
    Substitute: JAVA_HOME = C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51
    Substitute: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar = 
    Add classpath:  .
    Add classpath:  wfmgr_lib\jfxrt.jar
    Add classpath:  wfmgr_lib\junit.jar
    Add classpath:  wfmgr_lib\org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar
    Add classpath:  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
    Add classpath:  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
    Launcher:   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    Launcher args:  -Denv.path="C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Check Point\UIFramework 3.0\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\mysql-5.6.25-winx64\mysql-5.6.25-winx64/bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" -Denv.java.home="C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51" -Denv.c:\program.files\java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar="" -classpath "C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr_final\wfmgrexe.exe;.;wfmgr_lib\jfxrt.jar;wfmgr_lib\junit.jar;wfmgr_lib\org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" main.screens.ScreenFramework
    Args length:    1008/32768 chars
    Exit code:  0


    Version:    3.8
    CmdLine:    C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr_final\wfmgrexe.exe --l4j-debug
    WOW64:      yes
    Working dir:    C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr_final\.
    Bundled JRE:    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
    Check launcher: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (OK)
    Substitute: PATH = C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Check Point\UIFramework 3.0\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\mysql-5.6.25-winx64\mysql-5.6.25-winx64/bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
    Substitute: JAVA_HOME = C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51
    Substitute: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar = 
    Add classpath:  .
    Add classpath:  wfmgr_lib\jfxrt.jar
    Add classpath:  wfmgr_lib\junit.jar
    Add classpath:  wfmgr_lib\org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar
    Add classpath:  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
    Add classpath:  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
    Add classpath:  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar
    Launcher:   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    Launcher args:  -Denv.path="C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AXALTO\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Check Point\UIFramework 3.0\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\mysql-5.6.25-winx64\mysql-5.6.25-winx64/bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin;C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.3-bin\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" -Denv.java.home="C:\Users\a51217\Downloads\jdk-8u51" -Denv.c:\program.files\java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar="" -classpath "C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr_final\wfmgrexe.exe;.;wfmgr_lib\jfxrt.jar;wfmgr_lib\junit.jar;wfmgr_lib\org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar" main.screens.ScreenFramework
    Args length:    1049/32768 chars
    Exit code:  0
```

*image4j.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<launch4jConfig> <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar> <headerType>gui</headerType> <jar>C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr.jar</jar> <outfile>C:\Users\a51217\Desktop\wfmgr_final\wfmgrexe.exe</outfile> <errTitle/> <cmdLine/> <chdir>.</chdir> <priority>normal</priority> <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl> <supportUrl/> <stayAlive>false</stayAlive> <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash> <manifest/> <icon/> -<classPath> <mainClass>main.screens.ScreenFramework</mainClass> <cp>.</cp> <cp>wfmgr_lib/jfxrt.jar</cp> <cp>wfmgr_lib/junit.jar</cp> <cp>wfmgr_lib/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar</cp> <cp>C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib</cp> <cp>C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin</cp> <cp>C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar</cp> </classPath> -<jre> <path>C:\Program Files\Java\jre7</path> <bundledJre64Bit>true</bundledJre64Bit> <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback> <minVersion>1.6.0</minVersion> <maxVersion>1.9.0</maxVersion> <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference> <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits> <opt>-Denv.path="%PATH%"</opt> <opt>-Denv.java.home="%JAVA_HOME%"</opt> <opt>-Denv.c:\program.files\java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar="%C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jfxrt.jar%"</opt> </jre> -<messages> <startupErr>An error occurred while starting the application.</startupErr> <bundledJreErr>This application was configured to use a bundled Java Runtime Environment but the runtime is missing or corrupted.</bundledJreErr> <jreVersionErr>This application requires a Java Runtime Environment</jreVersionErr> <launcherErr>The registry refers to a nonexistent Java Runtime Environment installation or the runtime is corrupted.</launcherErr> <instanceAlreadyExistsMsg>An application instance is already running.</instanceAlreadyExistsMsg> </messages> </launch4jConfig>
```

Comment: There's no reference to my code in this exception. Plus, it works fine in eclipse and in my /Desktop. Everywhere else, this exception is thrown.

Comment: did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349303/how-to-make-jar-file-from-javafx-project

Comment: How are you building the Jar? Are you building a proper `MANIFEST.MF`?

Comment: I did @loli. Although the problem is different than mine, the answer is interesting nevertheless. The problem is that it's based on a building script and I'm almost sure there is an easier way since my application is working fine in the desktop directory.

Comment: I am using eclipse to export the project as a jar so yes, it automatically buids the MANIFEST.MF @durron597. I will add it to my question as an edit.

Comment: do you have a dependency on your desktop? If you create a folder on your desktop and put your files in it, the .jar stops working?

Comment: I don't think I have any dependencies on my Desktop other than project_lib (which I also move into the folder along the jar)@loli. It only works in my Desktop folder, as soon as I move it somewhere else, like a folder, it stops working.

Comment: I set my eclipse up so it compiles code compatible with java 7, although I have both 7 and 8 installed. I'll add that info to my question @Gimby

Comment: I can't explain exactly what is happening, but my gut is telling me that the problem happens when you have a JavaFX 7 runtime jar on the classpath and you try to run this using Java 8. When running through Java 8 the JavaFX 8 runtime must be on the classpath - hence that I find it odd that it is added to the classpath manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know exactly how I did it but it's fixed. I deleted all dependencies on my project's eclipse build path configurations. Then, I individually added each dependency and system library (in this case I added the jre7 and the jfxrt.jar).
It might have been the fact that I had referenced both system libraries (jre7 and jdk8) in my project, so special thanks to @Gimby for the tip.
Thanks guys!

Comment: In your new setup, is any javafx jar being added as an external library to your application inside that wfmgr_lib/ folder?

Comment: No, I'm no longer exporting the wfmgr_lib, I'm exporting a jar with the libraries extracted inside (default eclipse export settings). The only external jar that I added to the build path was the jfxrt.jar, which path is now the default JRE7 jfxrt.jar directory - `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib`

Comment: The path is hardcoded? That will mean the application will likely not run on other computers though.

Comment: That's true but it should work in all computers of my company's network. I'll try to add flexibility to the path later on, if I'm able to.

Comment: I wonder if it just keeps on working if you remove the class-path reference to JavaFX altogether. That seems like some legacy from the days it was first introduced and a separate installation from the Java runtime

Comment: Also: are you aware you can generate an executable wrapper for JavaFX applications? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm

Comment: I was aware there were wrappers like Launch4j but I didn't know there was a native way to do it. Thanks you very much for the info! :D @Gimby